# Push contents of one field to another field (array) if condition is satisfied - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

**This is not what I'm looking for:** [Update MongoDB field using value of another field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974985/update-mongodb-field-using-value-of-another-field)

I am trying to copy the contents of one field, into another field (which happens to be an array) if a condition evaluates to true.

**Initial document state:**

```
{
   _id: 1234
   currentNumber: 5
   magicNumbers: [3, 7, 9, 11, 15]
}
```

I want to copy contents of `currentNumber` to `magicNumbers` if `currentNumber % 2 == 1`. Is this possible in the latest MongoDB version? I'm using Nodejs driver.

**Final document state:**

```
{
   _id: 1234
   currentNumber: 5
   magicNumbers: [3, 7, 9, 11, 15, 5]
}
```

I want to do this in a single pass, to save trips to the database.

Comment: How are you currently doing it? When you have a current state, you request DB to return it and then update things?

Comment: Yes 2 trips. One to fetch, locally evaluate, then update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
db.collection.update({
  $expr: {
    $eq: [ { $mod: [ "$currentNumber", 2 ] }, 1 ]
  }
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      magicNumbers: {
        $concatArrays: [ "$magicNumbers", [ "$currentNumber" ] ]
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  "multi": true
})
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/M1GSRWVq3ME)

Comment: This is what im looking for. Another related question -- is it possible to replace "$currentNumber" with another integer which I have defined in nodeJS, say ```const randomNumber```

Comment: @Satya Sure you can. Change `[ "$currentNumber" ]` into `[ randomNumber ]`

Comment: Finally, can I replace the  expression in such a way that ```$currentNumber``` is greater than some ```lowerLimit```?

Comment: @Satya change `$eq: [ { $mod: [ "$currentNumber", 2 ] }, 1 ]` into `$gt:[ "$currentNumber", lowerLimit ]`